# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SessionStrategy | undefined'

Tags: typescript, next-auth

I am use next-auth for authorization in next project and use typescript, when I assign 'jwt' to strategy, a warn for type error occur: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SessionStrategy | undefined'.

my code:

```
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
```

type code: these type are all the official type, no declare by myself

```
export interface NextAuthOptions {
...
session?: Partial<SessionOptions>;
...
}
```

```
type Partial<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: T[P] | undefined; }
```

```
export interface SessionOptions {
...
strategy: SessionStrategy;
...
}
```

```
export declare type SessionStrategy = "jwt" | "database";
```

[image]

Comment: `Partial` is already a builtin typescript utility type and it behaves exactly as you have declared. Your code compiles tho: [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoQM4eAexAeQAcxcQNkBvAKAzCjkgHMBPALjU2z1ToYhYDcVAL5UqoSLEQoAchAAeYAIIBXMAAsiJPOWoZOpAPzsACnCgk4AGwA86LKS2kMAPiGiqYZoRT2uIHnomZmQAXmQAIgArAHcwCOQAH0iAEwY4ACM4fQihKgQdMGRIWnY5RVUNJx0wyipkBuR9Bzx2akam3mD2AHJYsB765FFhIA)

Comment: the declare keyword in the SessionStrategy type should be causing some problems. Do you have any reason for adding it?

Comment: I didn't add any type by myself. and I remove the declare keyword in the SessionStrategy type in the official type file, but it does nothing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

TLDR;

Add a type to the options object:

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
```

---

Explanation:

Imagine you have a function:

```
type GreetOptions = {
  greeting: 'hello' | 'hey'
  name: string
}

const greet = ({ greeting, name }: GreetOptions) => {
  console.log(`${greeting}, ${name}!`)
}
```

You could call it directly like:

```
greet({ greeting: 'hello', name: 'Joe' })
```

But then if you extract object to a variable, it fails...

```
const options = { greeting: 'hello', name: 'Joe' }

// ERROR! Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"hello" | "hey"'.(2345)
greet(options)
```

The compiler reads through the code in the same order that it would execute. So it first encounters the `options` variable. It doesn't read ahead in the code to try to figure out what you're going to do with it, it just infers a reasonable type for it:

```
const options: {
  greeting: string;
  name: string;
}
```

Then when you try to pass that to `greet`, the `string` type for `greeting` is not specific enough to match the argument type. However, you can help it out and declare what it should be:

```
const options: GreetOptions = { greeting: 'hello', name: 'Joe' }
```

And now it can check it and make sure that you don't do:

```
const options: GreetOptions = { greeting: 'goodbye', name: 'Joe' }
```

Comment: Just a note - The import statement to go with this fix is: import type { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the warn of type:
some telled me that 'jwt' just a string type by typescript view, so it could be anything that is a sting type, let's say 'foo' are also string type, so I can't assign it to a variable that's expecting a SessionStrategy,
since SessionStrategy can only be "jwt" | "database"

```
session: {
    strategy: 'jwt' as const,
},
```

should solve it,so TS doesn't turn "jwt" into string and stays narrowed to "jwt".

when this type warn disappear, I encounter another type warn:

```
Argument of type '{ providers: (OAuthConfig<GoogleProfile> | OAuthConfig<GithubProfile>)[]; adapter: Adapter; callbacks: { session: ({ session, token }: { ...; }) => Promise<...>; jwt: ({ user, token }: { ...; }) => Promise<...>; }; session: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NextAuthOptions'.
  The types of 'callbacks.jwt' are incompatible between these types.
    Type '({ user, token }: { user: any; token: any; }) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to type '(params: { token: JWT; user?: User | undefined; account?: Account | undefined; profile?: Profile | undefined; isNewUser?: boolean | undefined; }) => Awaitable<JWT>'.
      Types of parameters '__0' and 'params' are incompatible.
        Type '{ token: JWT; user?: User | undefined; account?: Account | undefined; profile?: Profile | undefined; isNewUser?: boolean | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ user: any; token: any; }'.
          Property 'user' is optional in type '{ token: JWT; user?: User | undefined; account?: Account | undefined; profile?: Profile | undefined; isNewUser?: boolean | undefined; }' but required in type '{ user: any; token: any; }'.ts(2345)
```

and fix it with:

```
import type { User } from 'next-auth';
import { JWT } from 'next-auth/jwt';

jwt: async ({ user, token }: { user?: User | undefined; token: JWT }) => {
      if (user) {
        token.uid = user.id;
      }
      return token;
    },
```

the final code as the picture:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, but this is not how you should fix this. You want your object to be of a specific type. The specific type is provided by the library. Declare it as the specific type. The compiler will do all of this automatically.

Comment: could you give me the right code, I have read your answer, but I still didn't know how to fix my code.

Comment: It's in the first line. You currently have `const authOptions = {`. Add the type like: `const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {`. You'll need to import the type, which the editor will probably do for you, but you could combine the imports into `import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'`

Comment: please help me anther problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74253027/how-to-made-the-user-model-augmentable